# Can't install PHPUnit using PEAR on Linux

Tags: linux, pear

I'm trying to install PHPUnit on my system using pear.
after discovering and updating the channel, when I try to install PHPUnit using the following command:

```
sudo pear install phpunit/PHPUnit
```

I get the following error:

```
No releases for package "phpunit/PHPUnit" exist
Install failed
```

Any ideas on how to solve this problem?
OS is Arch Linux 64 bit.

Comment: The same error on Windows 7 x64...

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `yum install php-pear-PHPUnit`?